# onClose event is not called on cancel click in simple modal...when i am loading another jquery dialog on simple modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Eric martin simple modal (1.3)to show some dynamic data (table) this table is clickable (when i click cells of table which i am showing on simple modal) , I am showing another popup jquery dialog which is also showing some content.....here i got  the problem .
 After my 2nd popup (jquery dialog) when i am closing my simple modal window onClose event is not called and not closing modal window.

```
// My main jsp page lil code snippet
     <script> 
         $("#eric").modal({
             onShow: function(){alert("show");},
             onClose: function(){alert("close ");
             $.modal.close(); }
         });
     </script>

     <body>
         <div id="eric"></div>
         <div id="rfi"></div>
     </body>

 // showing this dialog over simple modal dialog
        $("#rfi").dialog({
             //some dynamic data ajax call writing on dialog
              $("rfi").html(data);
         });
```

please help me i had already spent 3 days on this......:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  //got it
            $("#basic-modal-content").modal( {
    onShow : function() {
        activateDashBoardReverseAJAX(facilityId);  //called when simple   modal pop-up comes-up

    },
    onClose : function() {
        deActivateDashBoardReverseAJAX(facilityId);   //called when we close simple-modal pop-up
        var a = this;
        a.close();
    }

});
```